# How to create a login and user that can only access one schema in one database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, schema, permissions, logins

I have executed the following:

```
USE [MyDatabase];
GO
CREATE LOGIN [MyDomain\MyAccount] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[MyDatabase];
CREATE USER [MyDomain\MyAccount] FOR LOGIN [MyDomain\MyAccount];
GRANT EXECUTE   ON SCHEMA::[MySchema] TO [MyDomain\MyAccount];
GRANT SELECT    ON SCHEMA::[MySchema] TO [MyDomain\MyAccount];
GRANT INSERT    ON SCHEMA::[MySchema] TO [MyDomain\MyAccount];
```

(I am not granting any roles as I do not want this login to be able to access any other schema in this database.)

I run SSMS as MyDomain\MyAccount (run as a different user). I then try to connect to this instance. However, I am getting:

> Cannot open user default database. Login failed. Login failed for user
>   'MyDomain\MyAccount'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 4064)

I get the same result if I set the default database to MyDatabase in the Connection Properties.

I ran a Profiler trace and see an error 18456 state 38:

> Login failed for user 'MyDomain\MyAccount'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'MyDatabase'. [CLIENT: MyIpAddress]

That is followed by an error 18456 state 40:

> Login failed for user 'MyDomain\MyAccount'. Reason: Failed to open the
>   database 'MyDatabase' specified in the login properties. [CLIENT:
>   MyIpAddress]

MyDatabase is online and I have no trouble connecting to it with a different login. What additional permission do I need to grant to MyDomain\MyAccount? Is there something else that I am missing?

Comment: Have you verified the login is enabled?

Comment: @Steve: The login is enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off guess you are missing the connect permission.  I'd always thought that was created with the user but there may be conditions where it isn't added.

Try running

```
USE [MyDatabase];
GO
GRANT CONNECT TO [MyDomain\MyAccount];
```

You could also try changing the default schema of [MyDomain\MyAccount]

```
ALTER USER [MyDomain\MyAccount] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = MySchema;
```

Lastly you can use my [sp_dbpermissions](http://sqlstudies.com/free-scripts/sp_dbpermissions/) and [sp_srvpermissions](http://sqlstudies.com/free-scripts/sp_srvpermissions/) to review the permissions for the user.

```
EXEC sp_srvpermissions 'MyDomain\MyAccount'; -- Return instance level permissions
EXEC sp_dbpermissions 'All','MyDomain\MyAccount'; -- Return DB level permissions for all databases
```

Comment: GRANT CONNECT TO [MyDomain\MyAccount]; solved it. Apparently that was not being automatically granted in this case. Thanks!

Comment: LOL...that was my next question.  Amazingly, depending on the version and environnment - especially when scripting logins - the connect permission is almost always missing and the login is disabled.  Nice work Mark